# How to create a join in Dataframe based on the other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, mapping

I have 2 dataframes. One containing student batch details and another one with points. I want to join 2 dataframes.

Dataframe1 contains

```
+-------+-------+-------+--+
|  s1   |  s2   |  s3   |  |
+-------+-------+-------+--+
| Stud1 | Stud2 | Stud3 |  |
| Stud2 | Stud4 | Stud1 |  |
| Stud1 | Stud3 | Stud4 |  |
+-------+-------+-------+--+
```

Dataframe2 contains

```
+-------+-------+----------+--+
| Name  | Point | Category |  |
+-------+-------+----------+--+
| Stud1 |    90 | Good     |  |
| Stud2 |    80 | Average  |  |
| Stud3 |    95 | Good     |  |
| Stud4 |    55 | Poor     |  |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

I am trying to map the mark in the same dataset for each student.

```
+-------+-------+-------+----+----+----+
| Stud1 | Stud2 | Stud3 | 90 | 80 | 95 |
| Stud2 | Stud4 | Stud1 | 80 | 55 | 90 |
| Stud1 | Stud3 | Stud4 | 90 | 95 | 55 |
+-------+-------+-------+----+----+----+
```

I tried below code but it is replacing the values one by one.

```
s = df3['p1'].map(dfnamepoints.set_index('name')['points'])
df4 = df3.drop('p1', 1).assign(points = s)
```

Comment: If this is related to pandas you should add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working same if all values from `df3` exist in column `Name`:

```
s = dfnamepoints.set_index('Name')['Point']
df = df3.join(df3.replace(s).add_prefix('new_'))
```

Or:

```
df = df3.join(df3.apply(lambda x: x.map(s)).add_prefix('new_'))
```

Or:

```
df = df3.join(df3.applymap(s.get).add_prefix('new_'))

print (df)
      s1     s2     s3  new_s1  new_s2  new_s3
0  Stud1  Stud2  Stud3      90      80      95
1  Stud2  Stud4  Stud1      80      55      90
2  Stud1  Stud3  Stud4      90      95      55
```

If not, output is different - for not exist values (`Stud1`) get `NaN`s:

```
print (dfnamepoints)
    Name  Point Category
0  Stud2     80  Average
1  Stud3     95     Good
2  Stud4     55     Poor

df = df3.join(df3.applymap(s.get).add_prefix('new_'))
#or 
df = df3.join(df3.applymap(s.get).add_prefix('new_'))

print (df)
      s1     s2     s3  new_s1  new_s2  new_s3
0  Stud1  Stud2  Stud3     NaN      80    95.0
1  Stud2  Stud4  Stud1    80.0      55     NaN
2  Stud1  Stud3  Stud4     NaN      95    55.0
```

And for `replace` get original value:

```
df = df3.join(df3.replace(s).add_prefix('new_'))
print (df)
      s1     s2     s3 new_s1  new_s2 new_s3
0  Stud1  Stud2  Stud3  Stud1      80     95
1  Stud2  Stud4  Stud1     80      55  Stud1
2  Stud1  Stud3  Stud4  Stud1      95     55
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativey, you could use `df.replace()` after creating a dictionary of the 2 concerned columns of `df2` :

```
pd.concat([df1,df1.replace(dict(zip(df2.Name,df2.Point))).add_prefix('new_')],axis=1)
```

**Output**:

```
      s1     s2     s3  new_s1  new_s2  new_s3
0  Stud1  Stud2  Stud3      90      80      95
1  Stud2  Stud4  Stud1      80      55      90
2  Stud1  Stud3  Stud4      90      95      55
```

Comment: @DevAnanth pleasure. :)

Comment: One more question, what is I had another column S4 but I dont want to apply mapping for that column? Can we specify the column for which transformation is needed?