# How to count the category in one dataframe based on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I want to add the count of type of student for each row in a dataset based on the details in another dataset.

I have 2 dataframes. One containing student batch details and another one with points. I want to join 2 dataframes.

Dataframe1 contains

```
+-------+-------+-------+--+
|  s1   |  s2   |  s3   |  |
+-------+-------+-------+--+
| Stud1 | Stud2 | Stud3 |  |
| Stud2 | Stud4 | Stud1 |  |
| Stud1 | Stud3 | Stud4 |  |
+-------+-------+-------+--+
```

Dataframe2 contains

```
+-------+-------+----------+--+
| Name  | Point | Category |  |
+-------+-------+----------+--+
| Stud1 |    90 | Good     |  |
| Stud2 |    80 | Average  |  |
| Stud3 |    95 | Good     |  |
| Stud4 |    55 | Poor     |  |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

I am trying to map the number of people in each category in the same dataset for each row.

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+---------+------+
|  S1   |  S2   |  S3   | Good | Average | Poor |
+-------+-------+-------+------+---------+------+
| Stud1 | Stud2 | Stud3 |    2 |       1 |    0 |
| Stud2 | Stud4 | Stud1 |    1 |       1 |    1 |
| Stud1 | Stud3 | Stud4 |    2 |       0 |    1 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+---------+------+
```

I tried below but didn't work

```
s = df.set_index('Name')['Category']
df6 = df5.join(df5.replace(s).add_prefix('Type_'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of answer is same like in [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607134/2901002), only `replace` by another `Series` with `Category`, then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), replace missing values to `0` and last convert all to integers:

```
s1 = dfnamepoints.set_index('Name')['Category']
df = df3.join(df3.replace(s1).apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
      s1     s2     s3  Average  Good  Poor
0  Stud1  Stud2  Stud3        1     2     0
1  Stud2  Stud4  Stud1        1     1     1
2  Stud1  Stud3  Stud4        0     2     1
```

EDIT: For specify columns for replace use subset with `list`:

```
s = dfnamepoints.set_index('Name')['Category']
cols = ['s1','s2','s3']
df = df3.join(df3[cols].replace(s).apply(pd.value_counts, 1).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I do below one even this comes in the new columns. Is there any way to specify the columns we need count? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607134/2901002

Comment: @DevAnanth - First part seems same, but need another column for replace from previous answer - change `s = dfnamepoints.set_index('Name')['Point']` to `s1 = dfnamepoints.set_index('Name')['Category']` and then add `apply` after `replace`

Comment: I dont know if I explained the problem correctly. In the above example lets say I have another column s4 but I dont want to transform it. I want to count the category only for s1, s2 & s3.

Comment: @DevAnanth - I understand now, please check edited answer. Same solution is for previous answer.

Comment: this is what I am looking for exactly. Thanks a lot.